# Get line counts of INSERT's by tablename from mysqldump - awk, sed, grep

Tags: sed, group-by, awk, grep, mysql

bash master needed...

To compare mysqldumps from multiple dates, I need sql GROUP BY, ORDER BY functionality... but on the command line...

Using grep / sed / awk I need to look for all INSERT statements, then export a line count per tablename. I'd really love a byte count per tablename too...

A typical line looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `admin_rule` ...
```

match the INSERT, then match the tablename in ``, counting by unique tablename

Comment: a more comprehensive input/output description would get you better answers. Say for example a list of 3-5 input entries and what you expect to see as the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this little awk snippet:

```
BEGIN   { FS="`" }
/^INSERT/ { count[$2]+=1; bytes[$2]+=length($0) }
END { for(table in count) print table "," count[table] "," bytes[table]; }
```

Edit: test case here:

```
$ cat test.sql
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES('a', 12, 'b');
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES('test', 'whatever', 3.14);
INSERT INTO `t3` VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES('yay', 'works', NULL);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES(NULL, 'something' 2.71);
INSERT INTO `t3` VALUES(5, 6, 7, 8);
INSERT INTO `t5` VALUES('beta', 'gamma');
INSERT INTO `t6` VALUES('this', 'is', 'table', 'six');
$ awk -f t.awk <test.sql
t5,1,41
t6,1,54
t1,1,38
t2,3,144
t3,2,72
```

Comment: looks like this is getting first or last values, but not summing all records: eg:
catalog_category_flat_store_1,1,3457
core_store,1,196
catalog_category_flat_store_2,1,3459
shipping_matrixrate,1,14765... but thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yeah, sample data would be nice. It does add them up for my dummy data:
<code>
$ cat test.sql
INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES('a', 12, 'b');
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES('test', 'whatever', 3.14);
INSERT INTO `t3` VALUES(1, 2, 3, 4);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES('yay', 'works', NULL);
INSERT INTO `t2` VALUES(NULL, 'something' 2.71);
INSERT INTO `t3` VALUES(5, 6, 7, 8);
INSERT INTO `t5` VALUES('beta', 'gamma');
INSERT INTO `t6` VALUES('this', 'is', 'table', 'six');
$ awk -f t.awk <test.sql
t5,1,41
t6,1,54
t1,1,38
t2,3,144
t3,2,72
</code>

Comment: I'm guessing the "byte count per table name" means of the actual data rather than the length of the SQL statement as a whole. And do an `asort()` in the END clause so you have the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Dennis: for any given table, the data size can be approximated by subtracting the fixed part of each line ('INSERT INTO 'table' VALUES();') times the number of such rows.

Comment: ah, I was wrong... this above answer is correct for an --extended-insert mysqldump file. mysqldump is aliased differently on this server than on other servers that I admin (--skip-extended-insert vs. --extended-insert) which means that I only have one line per table's data in the file.

Comment: meta: Don't have any other points to give... what's the StackOverflow correct practice for asking for counting <code>/\([^\)]*\)/</code> (regexp) per line instead?